# Debugging VSTO with a Command Argument

Tags: vsto

I am developing an Excel Add-In, and I'm seeing some bugs that are coming up when people start Excel by opening a Workbook. If they start Excel and then open a Workbook, everything is fine, but otherwise there are issues.

The problem is, I don't know how to debug this, as I can't start the debugger with an Excel command argument (as far as I know).

I'll add some detail as requested:

Inside the ThisAddIn.cs, I have 2 blocks of code that are giving me problems.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (isStarted) return;

        var xl = this.Application;
        xl.WorkbookOpen += WorkbookOpened;
        xl.SheetActivate += Workbook_SheetActivate;

        var workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook;

        WorkbookOpened(workbook);

        isStarted = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogIt($"Error 01 - {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

and:

```
private void WorkbookOpened(Excel.Workbook workbook)
{
    try
    {
        if (!isStarted)
        {
            var xl = this.Application;
            xl.WorkbookOpen += WorkbookOpened;
            xl.SheetActivate += Workbook_SheetActivate;

            isStarted = true;
        }

        int key = Application.Hwnd;

        dynamic srVers = null;

        if (workbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Count == 0) return;

        var srType = workbook.CustomDocumentProperties("InternalDocType");

        try
        {
            srVers = workbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Version");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            srVers = null;
        }

        if (srType.Value != "OurType") return;

        Globals.Ribbons.prRibbon.WorkbookOpened(workbook);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogIt($"Error 06 - {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

When someone starts Excel and opens the workbook, there are no errors. However, if someone opens Excel by opening the workbook (double-click in File Explorer, or right click Excel and choosing the workbook) I get the Error 06 then Error 01, both with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide more context: what kinds of issues / bugs?

Comment: @CindyMeister it's a bit hard to explain, but I'll add to my original description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ESDictor, you can directly pass the path of the excel file as command line argument in visual studio.[image]