# How to Use an existing Excel document to debug my VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsto, excel-addins, visual-studio-2019

I have to come for help because after like 2 hours of web search I have not achieved what I want to do.
I start building a VSTO add-in using Studio 2019. I need VS to start in my current existing Excel workbook and not with a blank one made fresh on Debug launch. This page from MS tells me how to do it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio) and is quite well done. The information is under the section "Use an existing document to debug the add-in". I have followed the steps but step #7 does not show the "Start Document list" on my computer... 
I have found a workaround attaching my project solution to the excel process but that needs to be re-attached manually each time I debug my solution which is more than a pain when I launch it 10 times in a minute... I need a more sustainable solution and the one provided by MS to work some way or another.
Does anyone have any clue how to do this at all?
Many thanks in advance

I have that same problem on a computer running VS2017, that "Start Document" option is not showing as well.

Comment: Hi @mol86 check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417958/debugging-vsto-with-a-command-argument/53555835#53555835.

Answer (score 2):

"Start Document" option is only available for **Excel Web Add-in**.

For VSTO Add-in you can do the following:

1. In project's properties specify to start Excel as external program
   [image]
2. In Start options Command Line arguments specify path to Excel file.
   [image]